# Applies constraint to specific defined routing in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

currently I have the following custom constraint in web api:

**IntegerConstraint.cs:**

```
public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out object value) && value != null)
    {
        string valueString = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (int.TryParse(valueString, out int resultValue) && (resultValue > 0 && resultValue <= int.MaxValue))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And I registered it at:

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();

    constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("Integer", typeof(IntegerConstraint));

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "MyWebAPI",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
    );
}
```

And I have used it in controller like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("API/GetID/{id:Integer}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetID([FromUri] int id) { ... }
```

It works fine, but when I have method that have route and call it like this:

```
[Route("API/GetID/Something")]
http://localhost/API/GetID/Something
```

it will trigger the **IntegerConstraint** class with *"Something"* as it is value, even though I didn't specify

> :Integer

in the route attribute

But, it works fine when I access like this and have a route like this (with 5 being the value):

```
[Route("API/GetID/{id:Integer}")]
http://localhost/API/GetID/5
```

Is there any ways that I can specify only that comes with

> {anyParameter:Integer}

that will calls the **IntegerConstraint** class?

I have suspected the **MapHttpRoute** in **WebApiConfig** that cause any routing that have similar like this:

> [Route("API/GetID/*something goes here")]

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "MyWebAPI",
                    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
                );
```

that causes the problem.

Is there any idea on how to solve this or is there any better way to achieve this? (basically I put a constraint is because I want validate the parameter integer that put into URL from `1` until `int.maxValue` only, but only applies to certain route parameter that I specify constraint on)

Thanks